# Querying a dataframe to return rows based on a list/ndarray of conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have a dataframe 'df':

[image]

And an array of numbers, called 'profiles':

```
[310, 47, 161, 51, 78, 162, 303, 314, 176, 54]
```

I'm trying to query 'df' on column 'dayNo' to only returns rows which match the array above (profiles), but not sure how. I attempted the below, but to no avail:

```
df2 = df.loc[df['dayNo'] == [np.array([profiles], dtype=bool)]]
```

Any help greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing with [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) :

```
df2 = df.loc[df['dayNo'].isin(profiles)]
```

Another method is [`pandas.DataFrame.query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) :

```
df2 = df.query('dayNo in @profiles')
```

Comment: Thanks @abokey, both returned exactly what I needed!